# Python simple interest calculation

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate how much monthly payment in order to pay off a loan in 12 month. use $10 as incremental.

```
Payment = 0
balance = float (1200)
interest = float (0.18)
MonthlyInt = interest/12.0

while balance > 0 :

    Payment = Payment + 10
    month = 0
    while month < 12 and balance > 0:
        IntPay = balance* MonthlyInt
        balance += IntPay
        balance -= Payment
        month += 1
print Payment
```

The correct answer should be 110, why am I getting 60?

Comment: Put your code through a debugger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main things generating the difference are:

- The balance should be reset to 1200 before looping through the 12 months again
- The payment should be deducted from the balance before calculating the interest

A couple smaller python things are:

- `float()` isn't needed around numbers like `0.18`, it's already a float
- `1200.` would imply that the number is a float, so `float()` isn't needed

Accounting for these things then:

```
Payment = 0
interest = 0.18
MonthlyInt = interest/12.0
balance = 1200.

while balance > 0 :

    Payment = Payment + 10
    month = 0
    balance = 1200.
    while month < 12 and balance > 0:
        balance -= Payment
        IntPay = balance* MonthlyInt
        balance += IntPay
        month += 1
print(Payment)
```

gives a result of `110`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing it. I tried using Brians example in the MIT edx course and was unable to get it to work in all cases.

this is how I did it.

```
def lowestpayment(x,y):
""" x = total balance due
    y = annual interest rate 
    Returns min payment needed to pay off debt in 1 year
"""
month = 0
balance = x
annualInterestRate = y
payment = 0
while balance > 0 and month <= 12:
    month = 0
    balance = x
    payment += 10
    balance = balance - payment
    monthlyint = balance*annualInterestRate/12
    balance += monthlyint
    month += 1
    if balance+(balance*annualInterestRate/12)*11-payment*12 <= 0:
        return payment


print("Lowest Payment: ",lowestpayment(35,0.25))
```

Answer (score 0):

Q..

> Write a Python program to input principal amount, rate of interest and number of  years with  appropriate prompts. Find simple interest and display all the details in the following format:
> Principal Amount : Rs. __________
> Rate of Interest : ____ %
> Number of Years : ____
> Simple Interest : Rs. __________
> Maturity Amount : Rs. __________

ANSWER::

```
# for input
p = float (input("ENTER PRINCIPLE AMOUNT : "))
r = float (input("ENTER RATE OF INTEREST : "))
y = float (input("ENTER NUMBER OF YEARS : "))
# SIMPLE INTEREST
si = (p * r * y)/100
# display
print("{0:25}: Rs. {1}".format("Principal Amount", p))
print("{0:25}: {1}".format("Rate Of Interest",r ),"%")
print("{0:25}: {1}".format("Number Of Years",y))
print("{0:25}: Rs. {1}".format("Simple Interest",si))
print("{0:25}: Rs. {1}".format("Maturity Amount",p + si))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but please learn to format your answers correctly. You should also include an explanation of why your answer is an improvement over  the other answers as this will help others to learn from  you.